# Is there a way to destructure state when using object.assign cleanly?

Tags: javascript, state, destructuring

I have an ESLint warning showing "Must use destructuring state assignment" due to the rules I'm using.

However, I can't see how to do this cleanly when using object.assign, is there a good way?

I could simply destructure in a line above, but I am just curious to know if there is a better way.

```
const tags = Object.assign({}, this.state.tags);
```

Comment: How about: `const tags = {...this.state.tags};`? I think your ESLint tries to point in that direction.

Comment: @zvona I wonder if it would prohibit that, though? Since you're still referencing `this.state.tags` rather than `const { tags } = this.state` - but then you can't have the `tags` variable referencing both the original object and the cloned object...

Comment: Don't think that would be an issue

Answer (score 0):

`const { tags } = this.state`

If you need a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2): `const { tags = {} } = this.state`

With the [object destructuring warning](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md), the linter is enforcing a specific way of assigning variables from hashes.  This warning will also come up when destructuring function arguments. eg `Component = (props) =>` vs `Component = ({ id }) =>`